# Is it better to apply to a job through a recruiter or directly?

Tags: interviewing

A few months ago I was approached by the CTO of a company asking if I wanted to interview for a position? This is a small company of around 20 developers. I said I cannot do that right now for personal reasons (needed to relocate to a different country). The CTO said it’s okay I can contact them when I feel ready, etc…

This week a contracted recruiter approached me for a position, but he only revealed it later which company it is for, and turns out, it’s the same company (and I also assume the same position). I didn’t mind, I accepted the interview in their online form, but now I am having second thoughts about this.

Should I have contacted the CTO instead? It feels a bit awkward that I am taking a longer route to be hired at this company. Also this will cost them more money as they will have to pay the recruiter too I assume. Would I have better chances if I contacted the CTO directly?

What is the best thing to do at this point?

**Note**: I can still cancel the interview with the recruiter and apply via the CTO, but should I? (I think legally it is ok). Which option is more beneficial in this case? Is it possible that I will not be hired because I “accidentally” involved a recruiter? (who costs extra money).

Comment: When you refused to the CTO initially, did you state the reason for refusal?

Comment: I said I like the company and the job looks great but at the moment I am personally not ready to relocate to a different country in a short time. He said its okay lets keep in touch and let him know if I am open to this change in my life.

Answer (score 4):

Recruiters cost the hiring company so if you don't use them, you have more room to negotiate salary.  There may be some personal benefit to using a recruiter if you don't like or aren't good at the negotiation aspect, but I'd recommend you go directly to the company instead.  To do this, you should be honest with the recruiter and tell them that you have been exploring a position with this company for a few months now and will be declining an interview offer through the recruiter.  Then you can contact the CTO and move forward in good faith.  Good Luck.

Comment: The recruiter doesn't want to be surprised by you already having been in contact with this company. You can also tell them that you've already declined the offer previously. They will usually understand that since you just now know what company it is, you can change your mind, especially with this kind of background with the company. I've had no problems with telling recruiters I either don't want to work for X company, I've already interviewed, or already applied for it previously. It keeps them from being awkward with their clients, so it's doing them a minor favor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the direct contact of the CTO (who asked you in person if you wanted to interview and to contact them), then it is better than doing this via a recruiter.

> This week a contracted recruiter approached me for a position, but he only revealed it later which company it is for, and turns out, it's the same company (and I also assume the same position).

Careful with that assumption there... you don't know for sure if this is the same position, and assuming such could end up in a surprise later on.

> What is the best thing to do at this point?

If you can still cancel with the recruiter, and you have the CTO's contact I would go for it. Remember to be polite and thank them for their offer when doing so (*and be sure to check with CTO first if the position is still available!*)

Before doing that, I also suggest you ask the recruiter for what position is the interview. If it is the same position, then definitely ask the CTO directly instead (if it's a different position see if seems appealing to you).